# c# array of objects how to sum object.a property based on object.b property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using c# .NET 4.8. I have an array of objects. The objects have  properties, I want to get the sum of all of one of the properties only if the other property is not null.

So if I have these 3 objects in an array:

```
myObject[] objectArray = [
    new myObject{ a = 1, b = 2 },
    new myObject{ a = 3 },
    new myObject{ a = 4, b = 5 }
];
```

I want to sum `myObject.a` only if `myObject.b` is not null, which in this case would be 5 (1 from `objectArray[0].a` and 4 from `objectArray[2].a`).

I'm trying to accomplish this with linq but am having an issue with figuring out the syntax to it.

I've tried this:

```
objectArray.Select(x => x.a).Where(x.b != null).Sum();
```

but trying to reference `x.b` in my `Where` statement gives me the following error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'x'

I'm stuck on how to format this linq query to get the value I need. If anyone could give me some instruction on how to accomplish what I've outlined in this question I would greatly appreciate it. A correct, clearly explained answer will be marked as accepted and upvoted. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? You assign an integer value to b. Is the type of b a nullable type?

Comment: Adding link where you got `.Where(x.b != null)` example/syntax could help... Otherwise looks like you did not even try to look up [samples in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) (which is offensive to even think about).

Comment: @Steve I have updated my post with the actual error Visual Studio is giving me.

Comment: `objectArray.Where(x => x.b != null).Sum(x = x.a);`  is probably closer

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP selects `a`'s first - your suggestion is not enough. There is something OP does not understand about enumerables (and possible lambdas) that their need help with... Maybe code shown in answers can help them to sort it out or at least improve the question so it is clear where the help is needed.

Comment: Just swap the `Select` and the `Where`: `objectArray.Where(x.b != null).Select(x => x.a).Sum();`

Comment: Sorry, and add `x =>` to the `Where`: `objectArray.Where(x => x.b != null).Select(x => x.a).Sum();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten that a Where expression receives the current item in the sequence enumerated. So it should be *Where(x => x.b != null)* but you need also to tell the Sum expression what you want to sum. The Select part is not needed at all.

So, assuming *b* is a nullable type (IE *int? b {get;set;}*) then you can get the sum of *a* where *b* is null in a simple way

```
var result = objectArray.Where(x => x.b != null).Sum(k => k.a);
```

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for. I'm coming from a php background which is where I got the idea for `Select` from in error. Marked as accepted answer and upvoted, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you want to do is filter it first and then add. Example:

```
public class O
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int? B { get; set; }
}

var initList = new List<O>
{
    new O {A= 1, B = 2},
    new O {A= 2},
    new O {A= 3, B = 2},
};

var sum = initList.Where(item => item.B != null).Sum(item => item.A);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i'd do it is like so:

```
var sum = objectArray.Where(x => x.b != null).Sum(x => x.a);
```